Calculate $\oint_{S} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{4z^3 + z} dz$ where $S = [2, 2i,−2,−2i, 2]$
Calculate $\oint_{S} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{4z^3 + z} dz$ where $S = [2, 2i,−2,−2i, 2]$
Using Partial fractions, the integral can be wrote as:
$$\oint_{\gamma_1} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{4z} dz - \oint_{\gamma_2} \frac{z e^{\pi z}}{4z^2 + 1} dz$$
Here, I am not sure what path(s) I am to use for $\gamma_1$ & $\gamma_2$. Does it remain the same path?
If so, using Cauchy's integral theorem, for $\gamma_1$, I get
$$\oint_{\gamma_1} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{4z} dz\\
= \oint_{\gamma_1} \frac{\frac{e^{\pi z}}{4}}{z - 0} dz$$
Hence, by Cauchy's Integral formula,
$2\pi f(0) = 2i\pi \frac{1}{4} = \frac{i\pi}{2}$
For $\oint_{\gamma_2} \frac{z e^{\pi z}}{4z^2 + 1} dz$, the function is analytic at $z_0 = \frac{i}{2}$ & $z_0 = -\frac{i}{2}$
Hence, $2\pi f(\frac{i}{2}) = \frac{i}{8}$ & $2\pi f(-\frac{i}{2}) = -\frac{i}{8}$
So, $\oint_{\gamma_2} \frac{e^{\pi z}}{4z^2 + 1} dz = 0$
And the total integral is $\frac{i\pi}{2}$?

If you prefer decomposition into partial fractions (in fact an unnecessary exercise in self-torture) you obtain  $$\begin{align}\oint\limits_S \frac{e^{\pi z}}{ 4z^3+z} dz &= \frac{1}{4}\oint\limits_S e^{\pi z} \left[ \frac{4}{z}-\frac{1/2}{z-i/2}-\frac{1/2}{z+i/2}\right] dz\\[5pt] &= \frac{2\pi i}{4}\left[ 4 e^0 -e^{i \pi/2}/2-e^{-i\pi/2}/2\right] \\[5pt]&= 2 \pi i.\end{align}$$
Recommendation: Using the residue theorem directly makes life much easier.

Your function $f(z) = e^{\pi z}/(4 z^3 + z)$ has poles at
$z = 0, i/2, -i/2$.  All of these are inside the path $S$ (assuming you mean the polygon with the vertices you gave),
so the integral should be the sum of the residues at those poles.

I cannot use Residuals. I can only answer using the Cauchy Integral Formula cited above

Great mind! I was puzzled about the path and didn't even think of polygon.
